# Button update node.js and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am trying to make a basic counter that works between browsers/computers. (I'm new at this). The button only works about 1/12th of the time. How do I make it more consistent?

Thanks!

My server side node.js looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var hits = 0;

app.get('/main.html', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('bye');
    next();
});

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('hello');
    next();
});

app.get('/add', function (req, res) {
    console.log('added hits');
    hits++;
});

app.get('/hitNum', function (req, res) {
    console.log('hits req');
    res.end(hits+'');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var server = app.listen(80);
```

My HTML looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>     
        <script>
            var add = function () {
                $.get('add');
            }

            window.setInterval(function (){
                $.get('hitNum').done(function (data){
                    document.getElementById('hits').innerText = data;
                }); 
            }, 500);

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick='add()' >Hi</button>
        <p id='hits'></p>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by changing the `/hitNum` controller: Instead of just calling `end()` it is preferred to explicitly set the status and the  body (via `status()` and `send()`, respectively). Here's how I'd write it:

```
app.get('/hitNum', function (req, res) {
    console.log('hits req');
    res.status(200).send('' + hits);
});
```

the `200` status indicates "SUCCESS".

One more thing:

Your `/add` controller does not send any response back. This means that your JS will not know if/when the `/add` request has been completed:

```
app.get('/add', function (req, res) {
  console.log('added hits');
  hits++;
  res.status(200).end();
});
```